# pyppeteer: `Page.newPage`関数の処理が途中で止まってしまう

Tags: python, pyppeteer

## 環境

- pyppeteer 1.0.2
- Python 3.10.2
- Ubuntu 22.04

  - VirtualBox v7.0.6 r155176を利用している
  - ホストOSはWindows11 Pro

## 問題点

pyppeteerでブラウザを操作したいです。
以下のコードを実行したところ、`page.goto`を実行する前で、処理が止まりました。

## 質問

下記のコードが途中で処理が止まってしまう原因と解決策を教えていただきたいです。

以下に記載のログで、最終行の`RECV: {"id":4,"result":{}}`以降は、1分以上待ってもログは出力されませんでした。

## 補足

先日Ubuntu18.04から22.04にバージョンアップしました。
Ubuntu18.04のときは上記のようなコード（厳密に一緒ではないが）は動きました。
Ubuntuのバージョンアップにより、何かが変わったのでしょうか？

---

**現状のコード:**

```py
import os
import asyncio
from pyppeteer import launch
from pyppeteer.browser import Browser
from pyppeteer.page import Page
from typing import Optional
import time

import logging

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

logging.basicConfig(format='%(levelname)-8s : %(asctime)s : %(name)s : %(message)s', level=logging.DEBUG)


async def main():
    logger.info("start 'launch()'")
    browser: Browser = await launch()
    logger.info("start 'newPage()'")
    page: Page = await browser.newPage()
    logger.info("start 'goto()'")
    page.goto("https://www.google.com/")
    logger.info(f"title='{page.title}'")
    await browser.close()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.new_event_loop().run_until_complete(main())
```

**ログ:**

```
$ python sample.py
DEBUG    : 2023-02-10 02:40:36,722 : asyncio : Using selector: EpollSelector
INFO     : 2023-02-10 02:40:36,723 : __main__ : start 'launch()'
INFO     : 2023-02-10 02:40:36,962 : pyppeteer.launcher : Browser listening on: ws://127.0.0.1:44795/devtools/browser/41f9db60-def6-4e84-86bb-47a8238e1269
DEBUG    : 2023-02-10 02:40:36,962 : pyppeteer.connection.Connection : SEND: {"id": 1, "method": "Target.setDiscoverTargets", "params": {"discover": true}}
DEBUG    : 2023-02-10 02:40:36,963 : websockets.client : = connection is CONNECTING
DEBUG    : 2023-02-10 02:40:36,963 : websockets.client : > GET /devtools/browser/41f9db60-def6-4e84-86bb-47a8238e1269 HTTP/1.1
DEBUG    : 2023-02-10 02:40:36,963 : websockets.client : > Host: 127.0.0.1:44795
DEBUG    : 2023-02-10 02:40:36,964 : websockets.client : > Upgrade: websocket
DEBUG    : 2023-02-10 02:40:36,964 : websockets.client : > Connection: Upgrade
DEBUG    : 2023-02-10 02:40:36,964 : websockets.client : > Sec-WebSocket-Key: x249CRPQgAIEzSuRpwfwWA==
DEBUG    : 2023-02-10 02:40:36,964 : websockets.client : > Sec-WebSocket-Version: 13
DEBUG    : 2023-02-10 02:40:36,964 : websockets.client : > Sec-WebSocket-Extensions: permessage-deflate; client_max_window_bits
DEBUG    : 2023-02-10 02:40:36,964 : websockets.client : > User-Agent: Python/3.10 websockets/10.4
DEBUG    : 2023-02-10 02:40:36,968 : websockets.client : < HTTP/1.1 101 WebSocket Protocol Handshake
DEBUG    : 2023-02-10 02:40:36,968 : websockets.client : < Upgrade: WebSocket
DEBUG    : 2023-02-10 02:40:36,968 : websockets.client : < Connection: Upgrade
DEBUG    : 2023-02-10 02:40:36,969 : websockets.client : < Sec-WebSocket-Accept: 1Vff/ccWM9WOTWKdZigUywH95zI=
DEBUG    : 2023-02-10 02:40:36,971 : websockets.client : < Sec-WebSocket-Extensions: permessage-deflate; client_max_window_bits=15
DEBUG    : 2023-02-10 02:40:36,972 : websockets.client : = connection is OPEN
DEBUG    : 2023-02-10 02:40:36,973 : websockets.client : > TEXT '{"id": 1, "method": "Target.setDiscoverTargets"...s": {"discover": true}}' [78 bytes]
DEBUG    : 2023-02-10 02:40:36,980 : websockets.client : < TEXT '{"method":"Target.targetCreated","params":{"tar...":"","attached":true}}}' [162 bytes]
DEBUG    : 2023-02-10 02:40:36,981 : websockets.client : < TEXT '{"method":"Target.targetCreated","params":{"tar...:"","attached":false}}}' [163 bytes]
DEBUG    : 2023-02-10 02:40:36,981 : websockets.client : < TEXT '{"method":"Target.targetCreated","params":{"tar...583B09AB22E3A6BCD11"}}}' [221 bytes]
DEBUG    : 2023-02-10 02:40:36,983 : websockets.client : < TEXT '{"id":1,"result":{}}' [20 bytes]
DEBUG    : 2023-02-10 02:40:36,984 : pyppeteer.connection.Connection : RECV: {"method":"Target.targetCreated","params":{"targetInfo":{"targetId":"28dc2d38-5e24-42c2-be8e-f584b819d067","type":"browser","title":"","url":"","attached":true}}}
DEBUG    : 2023-02-10 02:40:36,985 : pyppeteer.connection.Connection : RECV: {"method":"Target.targetCreated","params":{"targetInfo":{"targetId":"2e284177-55a4-4747-936f-8fcfce4daa84","type":"browser","title":"","url":"","attached":false}}}
DEBUG    : 2023-02-10 02:40:36,986 : pyppeteer.connection.Connection : RECV: {"method":"Target.targetCreated","params":{"targetInfo":{"targetId":"8FBB603CDE1315D86EB3E46D95B602D5","type":"page","title":"","url":"about:blank","attached":false,"browserContextId":"59BFB1FBAA9D2583B09AB22E3A6BCD11"}}}
DEBUG    : 2023-02-10 02:40:36,987 : pyppeteer.connection.Connection : RECV: {"id":1,"result":{}}
INFO     : 2023-02-10 02:40:36,988 : __main__ : start 'newPage()'
DEBUG    : 2023-02-10 02:40:36,989 : pyppeteer.connection.Connection : SEND: {"id": 2, "method": "Target.createTarget", "params": {"url": "about:blank"}}
DEBUG    : 2023-02-10 02:40:36,989 : websockets.client : > TEXT '{"id": 2, "method": "Target.createTarget", "par...{"url": "about:blank"}}' [76 bytes]
DEBUG    : 2023-02-10 02:40:36,998 : websockets.client : < TEXT '{"method":"Target.targetCreated","params":{"tar...583B09AB22E3A6BCD11"}}}' [210 bytes]
DEBUG    : 2023-02-10 02:40:37,000 : pyppeteer.connection.Connection : RECV: {"method":"Target.targetCreated","params":{"targetInfo":{"targetId":"341CA1FE1641430B96936CFA2DCA14FC","type":"page","title":"","url":"","attached":false,"browserContextId":"59BFB1FBAA9D2583B09AB22E3A6BCD11"}}}
DEBUG    : 2023-02-10 02:40:37,002 : websockets.client : < TEXT '{"id":2,"result":{"targetId":"341CA1FE1641430B96936CFA2DCA14FC"}}' [65 bytes]
DEBUG    : 2023-02-10 02:40:37,003 : pyppeteer.connection.Connection : RECV: {"id":2,"result":{"targetId":"341CA1FE1641430B96936CFA2DCA14FC"}}
DEBUG    : 2023-02-10 02:40:37,008 : websockets.client : < TEXT '{"method":"Target.targetInfoChanged","params":{...583B09AB22E3A6BCD11"}}}' [225 bytes]
DEBUG    : 2023-02-10 02:40:37,010 : websockets.client : < TEXT '{"method":"Target.targetCrashed","params":{"tar...ashed","errorCode":31}}' [124 bytes]
DEBUG    : 2023-02-10 02:40:37,011 : pyppeteer.connection.Connection : RECV: {"method":"Target.targetInfoChanged","params":{"targetInfo":{"targetId":"341CA1FE1641430B96936CFA2DCA14FC","type":"page","title":"","url":"about:blank","attached":false,"browserContextId":"59BFB1FBAA9D2583B09AB22E3A6BCD11"}}}
DEBUG    : 2023-02-10 02:40:37,013 : pyppeteer.connection.Connection : SEND: {"id": 3, "method": "Target.attachToTarget", "params": {"targetId": "341CA1FE1641430B96936CFA2DCA14FC"}}
DEBUG    : 2023-02-10 02:40:37,013 : pyppeteer.connection.Connection : RECV: {"method":"Target.targetCrashed","params":{"targetId":"341CA1FE1641430B96936CFA2DCA14FC","status":"crashed","errorCode":31}}
DEBUG    : 2023-02-10 02:40:37,015 : websockets.client : > TEXT '{"id": 3, "method": "Target.attachToTarget", "p...430B96936CFA2DCA14FC"}}' [104 bytes]
DEBUG    : 2023-02-10 02:40:37,016 : websockets.client : < TEXT '{"method":"Target.targetInfoChanged","params":{...583B09AB22E3A6BCD11"}}}' [224 bytes]
DEBUG    : 2023-02-10 02:40:37,017 : websockets.client : < TEXT '{"method":"Target.attachedToTarget","params":{"...ingForDebugger":false}}' [297 bytes]
DEBUG    : 2023-02-10 02:40:37,018 : websockets.client : < TEXT '{"id":3,"result":{"sessionId":"5760D9CD965DC546B37FADB72DDFB0F3"}}' [66 bytes]
DEBUG    : 2023-02-10 02:40:37,019 : pyppeteer.connection.Connection : RECV: {"method":"Target.targetInfoChanged","params":{"targetInfo":{"targetId":"341CA1FE1641430B96936CFA2DCA14FC","type":"page","title":"","url":"about:blank","attached":true,"browserContextId":"59BFB1FBAA9D2583B09AB22E3A6BCD11"}}}
DEBUG    : 2023-02-10 02:40:37,021 : pyppeteer.connection.Connection : RECV: {"method":"Target.attachedToTarget","params":{"sessionId":"5760D9CD965DC546B37FADB72DDFB0F3","targetInfo":{"targetId":"341CA1FE1641430B96936CFA2DCA14FC","type":"page","title":"","url":"about:blank","attached":true,"browserContextId":"59BFB1FBAA9D2583B09AB22E3A6BCD11"},"waitingForDebugger":false}}
DEBUG    : 2023-02-10 02:40:37,022 : pyppeteer.connection.Connection : RECV: {"id":3,"result":{"sessionId":"5760D9CD965DC546B37FADB72DDFB0F3"}}
DEBUG    : 2023-02-10 02:40:37,023 : pyppeteer.connection.CDPSession : SEND: {"id": 1, "method": "Page.enable", "params": null}
DEBUG    : 2023-02-10 02:40:37,024 : pyppeteer.connection.Connection : SEND: {"id": 4, "method": "Target.sendMessageToTarget", "params": {"sessionId": "5760D9CD965DC546B37FADB72DDFB0F3", "message": "{\"id\": 1, \"method\": \"Page.enable\", \"params\": null}"}}
DEBUG    : 2023-02-10 02:40:37,025 : websockets.client : > TEXT '{"id": 4, "method": "Target.sendMessageToTarget... \\"params\\": null}"}}' [183 bytes]
DEBUG    : 2023-02-10 02:40:37,027 : websockets.client : < TEXT '{"id":4,"result":{}}' [20 bytes]
DEBUG    : 2023-02-10 02:40:37,029 : pyppeteer.connection.Connection : RECV: {"id":4,"result":{}}
```

## 追記

kuzira5186さんの回答で`page.goto`に`await`を付け忘れていたことに気付いたので、`await`を付けて再度実行ました。
しかし、、変らず処理が途中で止まり、pythonコマンドは終了しませんでした。

Comment: https://github.com/pyppeteer/pyppeteer/issues/248#issuecomment-1201841288 が関係しているかもしれない。

Comment: 御自身で見つけたIssueやkuzira5186さんの回答では全部に`await`が付いているので、少なくともその辺の変更を試してみてはどうでしょう？ [pyppeteer-チュートリアル](https://zenn.dev/mook_jp/articles/pyppeteer-simple-tutorial), [【Techの道も一歩から】第45回「pyppeteerを使いヘッドレスブラウザでログインして情報を取得する」](https://buildersbox.corp-sansan.com/entry/2022/01/20/110000)

Comment: ありがとうございます。試してみましたが、結果は変わりませんでした。

Comment: こちらの環境(Ubuntu 22.04/Google Chrome 111.0.5563.64)では `launch` で `--no-sandbox` を指定すると問題なく実行されます。`browser: Browser = await launch(args=['--no-sandbox'])` また、`page.goto()` にも `await` が必要です。

Comment: それから、`page.title` は attribute value ではなく method なので `logger.info(f"title='{await page.title()}'")` とする必要があります。

Comment: metropolissさん、ありがとうございます。動くようになりました。
ちなみになぜ`--no-sandbox`を指定しないと動かなかったのでしょうか？
結局この問題はUbuntuのバージョンアップによるものなのでしょうか？

Comment: 以下のサイトをなんとなく眺めました。

* [puppeteerで--no-sandboxを付ける理由は何なのか](https://scrapbox.io/yuta0801/puppeteer%E3%81%A7--no-sandbox%E3%82%92%E4%BB%98%E3%81%91%E3%82%8B%E7%90%86%E7%94%B1%E3%81%AF%E4%BD%95%E3%81%AA%E3%81%AE%E3%81%8B)

* [Setting Up Chrome Linux Sandbox](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/docs/troubleshooting.md#setting-up-chrome-linux-sandbox)

* https://no-sandbox.io/

Comment: pyppeteer と puppeteer の GitHub リポジトリの issues を眺めてみましたが、これといった情報は見当たりませんね。。2018年頃に sandbox 関連のオプションが追加されたのですが、その後削除されています。Ubuntu 18.04 から Ubuntu 22.04 へのアップデートで関連がありそうなのは systemd と AppArmor くらいしか思い浮かびません。

Comment: なるほど、ありがとうございます。
またmetropolisさんは、どのようにして「`--no-sandbox`を指定すれば動くだろう」と推測できたのでしょうか？今後の参考にしたいです。

Comment: 以前、Java 関連のプログラムを調査していた際に今回の状況と似ている現象に遭遇したことがあって、原因は JVM の sandbox mechanism にありました。Chrome にも同じ様な機能があるのではないか、と思ってオプションスイッチを調べると `--no-sandbox` があったので、それを指定すると問題なく動作した次第です。ただ、yuji38kwmt さんが提示されたドキュメントにも書かれていますが、セキュリティレベルを下げる事になりますので、適切な対処方法が他にもあるかもしれません。

Comment: ありがとうございます！

Answer (score 0, accepted):

metropolisさんのコメント通り、`launch`関数に`args=['--no-sandbox']`を指定したら、期待通り動くようになりました。

```
import asyncio
from pyppeteer import launch
from pyppeteer.browser import Browser
from pyppeteer.page import Page

import logging

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

logging.basicConfig(format="%(levelname)-8s : %(asctime)s : %(name)s : %(message)s", level=logging.INFO)


async def main():
    logger.info("start 'launch()'")
    browser: Browser = await launch(args=["--no-sandbox"])
    logger.info("start 'newPage()'")
    page: Page = await browser.newPage()
    logger.info("start 'goto()'")
    await page.goto("https://www.google.com/")
    logger.info(f"title='{await page.title()}'")
    await browser.close()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.new_event_loop().run_until_complete(main())
```

```
$ python sample.py
INFO     : 2023-03-14 08:09:35,321 : __main__ : start 'launch()'
INFO     : 2023-03-14 08:09:35,445 : pyppeteer.launcher : Browser listening on: ws://127.0.0.1:34889/devtools/browser/f12e7475-1b6d-481b-9cc6-55abbbc1ed8d
INFO     : 2023-03-14 08:09:35,449 : __main__ : start 'newPage()'
INFO     : 2023-03-14 08:09:35,535 : __main__ : start 'goto()'
INFO     : 2023-03-14 08:09:36,757 : __main__ : title='Google'
INFO     : 2023-03-14 08:09:36,758 : pyppeteer.launcher : terminate chrome process...
```

Answer (score 0):

`page.goto` も `await` が必要ですね！別の問題ならすみません！

```
await page.goto("https://www.google.com/")
```

Comment: ありがとうございます。確かにawaitが抜けていました。ただ、awaitを付けても、結果は変わりませんでした。